# Unable top Compile Class : MyClass cannot be resolved

Tags: java, jsp

```
`<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="com.login.*"%>
<%
String path = request.getContextPath();
String basePath = request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/";
%>
<html lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>
<% 
    String username = "";
        String password = "";
        if(request.getParameter("login") != null)
        {
            UserBean user = new UserBean(request.getParameter("username"),                 request.getParameter("password"));
            if(user.login())
            {}
}
%>
```

`

This is my JSP scriplet, and I have correctly imported the package  with name "com.login.*" in which my Classes are placed.

It is working fine on my local Apache Server 7.x but when I hosted this JSP project, it started giving this error :

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: 203 in the jsp file: /rat/login.jsp
UserBean cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: your class is called "MyClass" or "UserBean"?

Comment: @user2802192, make sure that your class `UserBean` has no errors and is compiled ,side note: you should avoid using jsp scriplets, instead use jsp custom tags like `jsp:useBean`

Comment: @user2802192, I noticed this on the top of page import **`**

Answer (score 0):

I would check your classpath and ensure the compiled code for com.login.UserBean is on the classpath for your JSP container.

Comment: I have placed the .class files in the right directory i.e. WEB-INF/classes/com/login/UserBean.class, but could you please tell me if there is anything else which i have to do ?